# URL redirect issue.in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I create a new record, I'm trying to redirect to the edit page with this.

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Organization", new { OrgId = organization.OrgId });
```

However, the result is this.

```
http://localhost:1626/Organization/Edit?OrgId=5
```

when it should be

```
http://localhost:1626/Organization/Edit/5
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your route map, which might look like this currently

```
"{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

to `"{controller}/{action}/{OrgId}"`

For further info: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Answer (score 1):

The default route pattern for the default route registration is `"{controller}/{action}/{id}",` So if you want a url with that strucutre, you may rename your action method parameter name to `Id`

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   // to do  : Return something
}
```

Another option is to use [Attribute routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) and specify this route pattern for the action method with your existing parameter (OrgId)

```
[Route("Organization/Edit/{OrgId}")]
public ActionResult Edit(int OrgId)
{
   // to do  : Return something
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I was just being slow on this saturday morning.I'll give you the check mark when it lets me.

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't changed your route table values,

Then you should change your action parameter to id instead of OrgId,

Or you should change your route table values from

`{controller}/{action}/{id}`

to

`{controller}/{action}/{OrgId}`